# Console.WriteLine as hexadecimal

Tags: c#, hex

The following code prints out `10`. How can I make it print out `a`?

```
int i = 10;
Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine ("Hex: {0:X}", nNum);
```

The X formatter outputs uppercase hex chars. Use a lowercase x for lowercase hex chars.

Answer (score 35):

i.ToString("x");

Comment: Very nice.  More on the [hexadecimal format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString).  Can change case and/or precision length as well.

Answer (score 20):

```
int i=10;
Console.WriteLine("{0:X4}", i);
```

Outputs hex with a size specifier.

you can also use string interpolation

```
int i=10;
Console.WriteLine($"{i:X4}");
```

Answer (score 15):

```
int i=10;

Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", i);
```

or if you want 'A':

```
int i=10;

Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", i);
```

Answer (score 7):

`Int32 num = 1024;`

#### Basic Hex Formatting

Using string interpolation:
`Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", num);`

Using built-in numeric string formatting:
`Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("X"));`

> `400`

#### Fixed Precision Hex Formatting

`Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("X4"));`

> `0400`

or

`Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x8}", num);`

> `0x00000400`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a format specifier:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", i);
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the format to `{0:x}`.